# Weird elements behaviour in the flexbox parent [Chrome Dev 95]

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

Chrome Dev so weird renders the flexbox. I just pin the screen

[What am I expecting and how does it display in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANdNv.png)

[Chrome Dev 95 | the image just filled the entire space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5eDS.png)

Images has a width: 100; height: 100%; styles, but in flex they will shrink to the same width

```scss
.tournament__grid {
  width: 100%;

  margin-top: 40px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px,  1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.grid__map {
  height: 340px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tournament__map {
  height: 100%;

  padding: 10px;

  &.multiply {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    padding: 0;

    .map__banner {
      position: relative;

      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;

      @include fontSize(24);
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: underline;

      background: $mainBlack;

      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center;
    }
  }
}
```

```pug
.tournament__grid
  .grid__map
    .map.tournament__map.multiply
      img.map__banner(src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?paris")
      img.map__banner(src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?paris")
      img.map__banner(src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?paris")
      img.map__banner(src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?paris")
      .map__banner +7
      .map__gradient
    .map__strip Lorem Ipsum
  .grid__column
  .grid__column
  .grid__column
```

Comment: Please add your css code also.

Comment: yup, no problem

Comment: Try adding `justify-content: center` to the `.multiply` class

Comment: Tried it and this doesn't work. I don't know why, but it is in Chrome the picture takes up all the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution, but it works

```
    .map__banner:nth-last-child(6):first-child, 
    .map__banner:nth-last-child(6):first-child ~ .map__banner {
      width: math.div(100%, 5);
    }

    .map__banner:nth-last-child(5):first-child, 
    .map__banner:nth-last-child(5):first-child ~ .map__banner {
      width: math.div(100%, 4);
    }

    .map__banner:nth-last-child(4):first-child, 
    .map__banner:nth-last-child(4):first-child ~ .map__banner {
      width: math.div(100%, 3);
    }

    .map__banner:nth-last-child(3):first-child, 
    .map__banner:nth-last-child(3):first-child ~ .map__banner {
      width: math.div(100%, 2);
    }
```